# Integrate function of two variables with respect to only one variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I want to integrate a 1D function using `quadgk` but for a different value of a parameter which is contained inside the integrand. Is there an easy way to do this? Below hopefully illustrates my problem:

```
function [out] = integrand(x,t)
#Calculations
end


t = linspace(0,1,10);
q = quadgk(@integrand,0,Inf, OPT_PARAM = t); #Apply quadgk on integrand for each value in t

plot(t, q) # q is a function of t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do it with a `for` loop?

```
function [out] = integrand(x,t)
%Calculations
end

t = linspace(0,1,10);
q = zeros(size(t)); % pre-allocate q
for k=1:length(t)
    q(k) = quadgk(@(x)integrand(x,t(k)),0,Inf); %Apply quadgk on integrand for each value in t
end

plot(t, q) % q is a function of t
```

More details on parameterising functions at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html.